# Mute HTML5 Video by default, But allow user to unmute

Tags: html, video

If I add the muted attribute to the  tag the video does mute, but the user cannot unmute the video using the default controls.

Is there anyway to have a video load up muted with the ability to unmute using default controls?

Comment: I've encountered this same issue. More details: IE 11, running in Edge mode. IE version 11.0.9600.18097.

Answer (score 1):

Use the muted attributed in order to mute the video.

```
<video controls muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: This is what is currently done...But if i add the Muted attribute within the video tag, I cannot unmute the video using the default controls...As explained in my original post.

Comment: if you try it here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video does it work?